# What is the logic to move a paddle left and right automatically on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am just developing a simple iPhone application where a paddle moves left and right automatically.

My logic:

```
// First to determine the CGPoint of paddle
CGPoint detectXY = CGPointMake(paddle.center.x ,paddle.center.y);

// Second to determine the velocity of paddle
CGPoint paddleVelocity = CGPointMake(1,1);

// Adding velocity with X,Y cordinate
paddle.center = CGPointMake(paddle.center.x + paddleVelocity.x, 
                            paddle.center.y + paddleVelocity.y);
```

But the paddle is not moving...

Any ideas?

Comment: And where (in what method of what kind of object) is that code?

Comment: Also, what is paddle?  A CALayer or UIView?

Comment: paddle is just a UIImageView .And the paddle movement i want  is as simillar as happen in a pong game.

Comment: How is the UIImageView created, in Interface Builder or all as code?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the **UIImageView** in Interface Builder, make sure you connect it up to your IBOutlet or it won't respond to you setting the **.center** property. This has bitten me many times.

Comment: Oh my god!!!
hw i m forget to connect the UIImageView ...Ok thnx for point it out .Now i am able to slide the image to one side But there still problem in it when paddle it reaches end point it is not moving right...i think i miss a condition for that .

Answer (score 0):

```
my updated code


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.9 target:self selector:@selector(game) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)game{

CGPoint imgVelocity = CGPointMake(20,1);
CGPoint detectXY = CGPointMake(imgViewPaddle.frame.origin.x , imgViewPaddle.frame.origin.y);

int x1= (int)detectXY.x;

  CGRect rect=imgViewPaddle.frame;

  if(x1>=0)
  {
imgViewPaddle.frame=CGRectMake(imgViewPaddle.frame.origin.x-imgVelocity.x, imgViewPaddle.frame.origin.y, imgViewPaddle.frame.size.width, imgViewPaddle.frame.size.height);

  }
  else  //<0
  {
   imgViewPaddle.frame=CGRectMake(imgViewPaddle.frame.origin.x+imgVelocity.x, imgViewPaddle.frame.origin.y, imgViewPaddle.frame.size.width, imgViewPaddle.frame.size.height);

  }

 rect=imgViewPaddle.frame;
}
```

Comment: This should be added to the original question & formatted as code for readability.